# Why my post showing not found in admin side when i click on count of category?

Tags: 404-error

i am building new theme in wordpresss and i posted some post inside my post with specific categories and when i click on `count` of category to see how many posts are of this category but every time i get `post not found`
can any one please guide me whats can be problem there...please check i uploaded an image below ..
[image]

what i am getting below is an image:
[image]

Comment: It's an old Wordpress bug, if I remember right. I encountered it myself a few times, Google will probably help you out.

Comment: Can you please send me link from where i can get help...?

Comment: I tried a couple of time but I am failed in solving this problem.

Comment: Did you take a look at the source code of this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-category-count/)? You might find a solution there.